# Multiple Data In Dropdown using ajax, json not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to pull data from database, the below code works fine and display drop-down of batch number if the batch number has only one record in database, but when i add more stock against same batch number it stops showing the drop down in batch number, on the other hand if i do the same code without json it shows all the batch numbers but i want to handle this with json because i have to pull some other data also from db that i will display in some other divs, kindly help what i am doing wrong.

**JQuery/Ajax**

```
<script>
    function getBatch(id) {

        var product_id = jQuery('#product'+id).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_Batch.php',
            data: { product_id: product_id },
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#batch'+id).html(data.batch_option);
                jQuery('#available_qty'+id).val(data.avaliable_quantity);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

include('includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['product_id'])) :

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $get_batch = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from products JOIN products_stock ON products.p_id='$product_id' AND products.p_id=products_stock.p_id");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_batch) > 0) :
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        while($batch = mysqli_fetch_object($get_batch)) :
            $data = [
                        'batch_option'          =>  "<option value=".$batch -> batch_no."> 
                                                        ".$batch -> batch_no."
                                                    </option>",
                        'avaliable_quantity'    =>  $batch -> p_available
                    ];
            echo json_encode($data);
        endwhile;
    else :
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $data = [
                    'batch_option'  =>  "<option value='No batch found'> No batch found </option>",
                    'avaliable_quantity'    =>  'Not avaliable'
                ];
        echo json_encode($data);
    endif;
endif;
```

?>

If i do like this it will show all record against one batch number in drop down

```
<?php

include('includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['product_id'])) :

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $get_batch = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from products JOIN products_stock ON products.p_id='$product_id' AND products.p_id=products_stock.p_id");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_batch) > 0) :
        while($batch = mysqli_fetch_object($get_batch)) :
        ?> <option value="<?php echo $batch -> id; ?>"><?php echo $batch -> id; ?></option> <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
endif;
```

?>

Comment: You need to move your `echo json_encode($data);` after your while loop. With it in the loop it is echoing multiple json encoded data, which is invalid. You will also need to change `$data = ...` to `$data[] = ...`

Comment: You will also need to loop over the json object in your JavaScript to get all of the returned html data

Answer (score 1):

Change your `while` loop so that `$data` is defined outside of it, and results are appended to `$data` within the loop

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = []; //will store results
while($batch = mysqli_fetch_object($get_batch)) :
    $data[] = [...];    //add next result       
endwhile;
echo json_encode($data); //encode and return all results.
```

In the Javascript, you will also have to change how you populate the HTML.  Your current code just adds `data.batch_option` and `data.avaliable_quantity` to your document. Once you have several results though, `data` will be an array, so you will not to loop through its members and add each member to the document.

```
success: function(data) {
    //loop through each result in data
    data.forEach(function(result){
        var opt = result.batch_option;
        var qty = result.avaliable_quantity;

        //Todo: add opt and qty to the right DOM elements
    });
}
```

Comment: I added a bit to get you started; I'm sure you'll work out the rest.

Comment: You're welcome Waleed. If I helped you solve your problem, be sure to select my answer as the solution.